# How to convert PHP string as name of a function and call the function

Tags: php

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
function getItems($arg) {
    $products = array();
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '0', 'title' => 'Product1');
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Product2');
    return $products;
}

$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems(\"Arg\")", "<div><h3>{$item->title}</h3></div>"]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonContent);

$options = $jsonObj->myKey;

if($options[0] == 'loop') {

    $html = [];

    foreach($options[1] as $item) {

        $html[] = $options[2];
    }

    echo implode('', $html);
}
?>
```

Of course, I get the warning

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...

because the argument for the `foreach()` is not an array but a string.

So how to convert a string as name of a function and call the function?

And how to use the third element of the `$options` array as a wrapper with dynamic data from the loop (I hope you will understand me by the code)

I need to get the following result:

```
<div><h3>Product1</h3></div>
<div><h3>Product2</h3></div>
```

Comment: The extra complication is you want to do the substitution of the value as well as the function call.

Comment: Are you generating the JSON yourself or is this coming from some external source? If it's your code generating the JSON, can you add the function argument(s) separately?

Comment: Yes, I can separate the name and the argument. Now I have valid array for `foreach()` but on the page I see `{$item->title}{$item->title}` So how to use item property like `$item->title` as dynamic data?

Comment: @stckvrw I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of it is to skip the foreach and just "run it" and input options[2] as argument, however since the string has `()` this had to be removed with substr.

```
$html = [];


$html[] =substr($options[1],0,-2)($options[2]);

var_dump($html);
```

https://3v4l.org/sE2bT

---

I see you asked of a different approach without the eval.

You can use str_replace in a loop in your function.
Because products are undefined when the string is created then the "" will not concert it to products value in the function.

But this will (I assume) give you the output you want.

```
function getItems($item) {
    $products = array();
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '0', 'title' => 'Product1');
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Product2');
    $return = "";
    foreach($products as $prod){
        $return  .= str_replace('$products->title',$prod->title, $item);
    }
    return $return;
}

$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems()", "<div><h3>{$products->title}</h3></div>", "<div><h1>{$products->title}</h1></div>"]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonContent);

$options = $jsonObj->myKey;

if($options[0] == 'loop') {

    $html = [];
    $func = substr($options[1],0,-2);
    foreach(array_slice($options,2) as $arg){
        $html[] = $func($arg);
    }

    var_dump($html);
}

/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(60) "<div><h3>{Product1}</h3></div><div><h3>{Product2}</h3></div>"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "<div><h1>{Product1}</h1></div><div><h1>{Product2}</h1></div>"
}
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/66Kv7

---

If you can't change the code in function then do the same processing in the "front".

```
function getItems() {
    $products = array();
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '0', 'title' => 'Product1');
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Product2');
    return $products;
}

$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems()", "<div><h3>{$products->title}</h3></div>", "<div><h1>{$products->title}</h1></div>"]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonContent);

$options = $jsonObj->myKey;

if($options[0] == 'loop') {

    $html = [];
    $func = substr($options[1],0,-2);
    $products = $func();

    foreach(array_slice($options,2) as $arg){ 
        foreach($products as $prod){
            $html[] = str_replace('$products->title',$prod->title, $arg);
        }       
    }

    var_dump($html);
}

/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "<div><h3>{Product1}</h3></div>"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "<div><h3>{Product2}</h3></div>"
  [2]=>
  string(30) "<div><h1>{Product1}</h1></div>"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "<div><h1>{Product2}</h1></div>"
}
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/1jT48

Comment: Ok, then try the latest version

Answer (score 1):

With the extra complication of adding in the value to the HTML, I can only think of the evil `eval`.  But for the rest, just separate the function name from the parameters and create them as an array in the JSON.  These can then be passed in using the Argument unpacking [`...`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator.  I've amended the function to show how the passed in arguments could work.

In the JSON I have

```
["Product", 3]
```

which maps onto

```
function getItems( $prefix, $start) {
```

So to put this together...

```
function getItems( $prefix, $start) {
    $products = array();
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '0', 'title' => $prefix.$start);
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'title' => $prefix.($start+1));
    return $products;
}

$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems", ["Product", 3], 
            "<div><h3>{$item->title}</h3></div>"]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonContent);

$options = $jsonObj->myKey;

if($options[0] == 'loop') {

    $html = [];

    foreach($options[1](...$options[2]) as $item) {
        $html[] = eval("return \"{$options[3]}\";");
    }

    echo implode('', $html);
}
```

which returns

```
<div><h3>Product3</h3></div><div><h3>Product4</h3></div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there another way to store the value with html wrapper for it?

Comment: Not that instantly comes to mind.  You should be safe as long as you keep the HTML under control - don't just let users put any random stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a string as your function, you need to remove the `()` from your string.

```
$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems", "<div><h3>{$item->title}</h3></div>"]}';
```

Then, on your `foreach()` loop, add them again after `$options[0]` like this:

```
 foreach( $options[1]() as $item) {
    $html[] = $options[2];
 }
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, here is a function argument. Added to my code

Comment: What should the argument be?

Comment: I can't answer because there may be different functions I don't know all at the moment. But at least a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is hackish and uses `eval` which can be dangerous on untrusted data, but for fun:

```
$arg = 'something';

if($options[0] == 'loop') {
    $func = rtrim($options[1], '()');

    foreach($func($arg) as $item) {
        eval("echo \"{$options[2]}\";");
    }
}
```

Or a slightly different approach without an argument:

```
if($options[0] == 'loop') {
    eval("\$items = {$options[1]};");

    foreach($items as $item) {
        eval("echo \"{$options[2]}\";");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use call_user_func to call a function from a string, and as pointed out by Andreas, use separate array positions for function and argument(s)

But I wanna point out that this is UTTERLY complicated and maybe not necessary... are there any other ways you can uncomplicate it ?

**EDIT**:

Why do you need to pass an arg that you don't even use anyway ?

`````
function getItems($arg) {
    $products = array();
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '0', 'title' => 'Product1');
    $products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Product2');
    return $products;
}

$jsonContent = '{"myKey":["loop", "getItems", "Arg1,Arg2", "<div><h3>{$item->title}</h3></div>"]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonContent);

$options = $jsonObj->myKey;

if($options[0] == 'loop') {

    $html = [];

    $args = explode(',', $options[2]);

    foreach($args as $item) {
        $html[] = call_user_func ($options[1], $item);
    }

    echo implode('', $html);
}
?>````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more workable with a couple of changes to the JSON.
First, I think it would make the code more readable if `options` was an object rather than an array, but this same approach should still work with an array if you prefer that. Second, I think the function arguments and any object properties used in the template should be separate options to avoid use of `eval()`.

```
{
    "myKey": {
        "type": "loop",
        "function": "getItems",
        "args": [
            "Arg"
        ],
        "template": "<div><h3>%s<\/h3><\/div>",
        "properties": [
            "title"
        ]
    }
}
```

The code for processing options after decoding the JSON:

```
if ($options->type == 'loop') {
    $html = [];
    foreach (($options->function)(...$options->args) as $item) {
        $html[] = vsprintf($options->template, array_map(function ($property) use ($item) {
            return $item->$property;
        }, $options->properties));
    }
    echo implode('', $html);
}
```

I would not recommend using this if the JSON would ever come from any external source. It seems like a good way to let people execute arbitrary code on your system, even without `eval`. Even if you're only using it yourself, I think it would still be prudent to at least validate the function name against a list of allowed functions.

---

Code for options array rather than object:

JSON:

```
{"myKey":["loop","getItems",["Arg"],"<div><h3>%s<\/h3><\/div>",["title"]]}
```

PHP:

```
if ($options[0] == 'loop') {
    $html = [];
    foreach (($options[1])(...$options[2]) as $item) {
        $html[] = vsprintf($options[3], array_map(function ($property) use ($item) {
            return $item->$property;
        }, $options[4]));
    }
    echo implode('', $html);
}
```